# Make a Function using recursion which will return all the reportee (Direct/ Indirect) of a manager as a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, logic, servicenow

I am trying to implement a scenarion in servicenow where I need to create a JSON object for all the reportee under a manager (direct / indirect).

I am getting

```
[
  "user1", ["user3", ["user4"]], 
  "user2", ["user5", ["user6","user7"], "user8", ["user9"]]
]
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "user3": ["user4"]
  },
  "user2": {
    "user5": ["user6", "user7"],
    "user8": ["user9"]
  }
}
```

This is a code in service now if anyone interested:

```js
function reportee(userID) {
  var userGr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
  userGr.addQuery('manager', userID);
  userGr.query();

  var reporteeArr = [];
  while (userGr.next()) {
    if (reporteeArr.indexOf(userGr.name.toString()) == -1) {
      reporteeArr.push(userGr.name.toString()); //We will push the reportee name if it's not already in array
      var subReportee = reportee(userGr.sys_id);
      if (subReportee.length > 0) {
        reporteeArr.push(subReportee); // learn how to concatenate
      }
    }
  }
  return reporteeArr;
}

var userID = 'd6ea959c471311103c8dda97436d4370'; // sys_id of users to find his/her reportees
var reportees = reportee(userID);
gs.info(JSON.stringify(reportees));
```

Comment: What's the result supposed to look like if `user6` is a manager/has reportees

Comment: Just like user 1,2,5,8 it will have it's own reportees

Comment: Please share the expected output in an [edit] if user6 has reportees, it's not clear how it should show it, do they need to be in a nested object _within_ `user5`'s array?

Comment: If you're after a "recursive" structure, then it would make more sense for your expected object structure to be consistent all the way through, so using objects instead of arrays, eg: `user5: {user6: null, user7: null}`, then if `user6` had children you could represent that: `user5: {user6: {userX: null}, user7: null}`. With your current structure, it's not clear to me how you would represent if user6 has children.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to use arrays, then I would suggest that you use an array all the way through your structure, like so `[{ user1: [{ user3: [{ user4: [] }] }] }, { user2: [{ user5: [{ user6: [] }, { user7: [] }] }, { user8: [{ user9: [] }] }] }]`, that way it's easier to write a recursive solution for this as the structure lends itself better to a recursive function.

Comment: NOw that I think about it, You are right. If there are let's say 4 user under a manager and only one has subordinates under him then other will have to store null or empty ""
something like this:
{
  "user1": {
    "user3": [
      "user4"
    ]
  },
  "user2": {
    "user5": {
      "user6": [
        "user10"
      ],
      "user7": null
    },
    "user8": [
      "user9"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: What makes your proposed structure difficult to work with is you're chainging between arrays and objects. You're representing the children of user2 with an object: `{ "user5": ..., "user7: ...}`, but then representing the children of `"user6"` with an array `["user10"]`. Why not remain consistent throughout your entire structure and just use objects `{"user10": null}` as I proposed above, to represent your children from `"user6"` as well as your other leaf-nodes as objects